# Get back to the same place in list after edit

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of 100 car models rendered by Ember. I scroll down to the bottom and click a car and get linked to `/cars/192/edit`
After edit I get transitioned back to `/cars`, but now I'm at the top of the list.

Is it possible to get back to the list exactly as it was when I clicked the edit link? Including checked checkboxes, expanded data and so on?

Comment: I think you will need to maintain the states - here is another post referencing a similar task - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425753/ember-js-where-should-interface-state-be-stored